# Creating instance of return type in generic method

Tags: c#, java, generics

I am looking to create a generic helper method in java that mimics the functionality of the following C# method.

```
private T Execute<T>(Request request) where T : Response, new()
{
     .... Code
}
```

The method above is called in the following cases

```
    public AddLogicalDeviceResponse AddLogicalDevice(AddLogicalDeviceRequest request)
    {
        return Execute<AddLogicalDeviceResponse>(request);
    }


    public GetConfigurationResponse GetConfiguration(GetConfigurationRequest request)
    {
        return Execute<GetConfigurationResponse>(request);
    }


    public GetDeviceDefinitionsResponse GetDeviceDefinitions(GetDeviceDefinitionsRequest request)
    {
        return Execute<GetDeviceDefinitionsResponse>(request);
    }


    public RemoveLogicalDeviceResponse RemoveLogicalDevice(RemoveLogicalDeviceRequest request)
    {
        return Execute<RemoveLogicalDeviceResponse>(request);
    }


    public GetEPCListCommandResponse GetEPCListCommand(GetEPCListCommandRequest request)
    {
        return Execute<GetEPCListCommandResponse>(request);
    }


    public DeviceSpecificCommandResponse DeviceSpecificCommand(DeviceSpecificCommandRequest request)
    {
        return Execute<DeviceSpecificCommandResponse>(request);
    }


    public GetConfigValuesCommandResponse GetConfigValuesCommand(GetConfigValuesCommandRequest request)
    {
        return Execute<GetConfigValuesCommandResponse>(request);
    }


    public SetConfigValuesCommandResponse SetConfigValuesCommand(SetConfigValuesCommandRequest request)
    {
        return Execute<SetConfigValuesCommandResponse>(request);
    }


    public UpdateFirmwareCommandResponse UpdateFirmwareCommand(UpdateFirmwareCommandRequest request)
    {
        return Execute<UpdateFirmwareCommandResponse>(request);
    }
```

Each of the above cases extends a class Response or Request in their respective situations.

I have attempted to create the same implementation as the above C# code using Java generics, but I have not had any success. Is it possible to implement the same functionality using only one helper method or am I forced to create a separate helper method for each individual type of call.

**EDIT :**

Here is my current Java implementation

```
private <T extends Response> execute(Request request)
{
    String url = request.BuildUri(_baseUri, _accessKey);
    Object[] response = Send(url, "");

    if(((Integer)response[1] == 200))
    {
        T jsResponse = new T();
        jsResponse.Body = (String)response[0];
        jsResponse.Request = url;
        return jsResponse;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ResponseException(response[1], response[2], url, response[0]);
    }
}
```

My current troubles stem from the function not being able to recognize the return as a valid object. Not being able to initialize the object T as a Response, and the T object not recognizing methods that are implemented in Response.

Comment: Could you show you Java attempt as well?

Comment: I have added my Java implementation as requested.

Comment: Answer undeleted it and updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, there's no way to create an instance of `T` class without sending `Class<T>` as parameter. Here's an example of using this for your current option:

```
interface Request {}

interface Response {
    public String sayHi();
}

class DeviceRequest implements Request {}
class DeviceResponse implements Response{
    public String sayHi() { return "DeviceResponse"; }
}

class WebRequest implements Request {}
class WebResponse implements Response{
    public String sayHi() { return "WebResponse"; }
}

class Helper {
    private <T extends Response> T execute(Request request, Class<T> clazz) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        return clazz.newInstance();
    }
    public DeviceResponse foo(DeviceRequest request) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        return execute(request, DeviceResponse.class);
    }
    public WebResponse bar(WebRequest request) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        return execute(request, WebResponse.class);
    }
}

class Consumer {
    public void baz() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        Helper helper = new Helper();
        DeviceResponse dr = helper.foo(new DeviceRequest());
        WebResponse wr = helper.bar(new WebRequest());
        System.out.println(dr.sayHi());
        System.out.println(wr.sayHi());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Consumer().baz();
    }
}
```

Note that since this is just an example, I prefered to just throw the Exceptions without handling them. For real world app, you should handle the exceptions instead of just throwing them.

Comment: Yuck. I don't like over-use of class literals, especially when a reflective constructor is involved. I think an execute method on the Request would be better suited in this case. Each execute method could be defined to return a more specific Response type as java allows covariant return types.

Comment: @jontejj yes but it adds more complexity to the design.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you define the generic parameter before the other parts of the signature.

```
private <T extends Response> T execute(Request request)
{
     .... Code
}
```

Comment: And where's `Response` in this?

Comment: There you go. Sorry for not noticing it:)

Comment: Since you don't have 10k+ rep, you can't see that I attempted the same in my deleted answer. Try this in your fav IDE and some examples of the implementation and tell me if it works :). (Removed the downvote, by the way).

Comment: This is as close as you can get in Java - note that there is no Java equivalent to the C# "new()" constraint.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas you can create new instances of `T` by passing `Class<T> clazz` as parameter to the method (which would be an *equivalent*).

Comment: Yes - that is a nice work-around to Java's lack of a 'new()' constraint.