# How to make a new Object of type T

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to make a new Object of type T.

I tried:

```
T h = new T();
T h = T.newInstance();
```

Those don't work. I also tried:

```
T h = (T)(new Object());
```

That works, but then `h.getClass().getName()` returns `java.lang.Object`

Is there any way to make a default object of this class without knowing the class name?

EDIT (from comments):

`T` is a generic. Like `Class<T>`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16859973/1065197

Comment: Is `T` a type parameter for a generic type here? If so, you'll need a `Class<T>` somewhere due to type erasure.

Comment: Google for "java reflection API"

Comment: Guys, T is not generics, T is USUAL class name :)

Comment: @AshotKarakhanyan we can't know that without confirmation from OP. If T was a usual class, `new T()` would have worked. (Assuming there is a default constructor)

Comment: T is a generic. Like Class<T>.

Comment: OK, @PitaJ, so why just now you informed about it. It assumes that you are creating a class witaot name, just generic name only :)))

Comment: Also you have write "Object of type T" not "Object of type F and with generic of type T", it is so dramatic :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Instantiating a generic class in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090458/instantiating-a-generic-class-in-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Jon commented you explictly need the class due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

E.g. if you have a generic method, you'll have to do it like this:

```
public void <T> myMethod(Class<T> clazz) {
    T foo = clazz.newInstance();
}
```

If it's a generic class it basically works the same. You just have to pass the class object to the metod or even to the constructor.

Comment: This will work assuming the class has a default constructor e.g. `class Foo { public Foo() {} }`.

Comment: I'm getting IllegalAccessException and InstantiationException now.

Comment: But we don't need generics... :)

Comment: @AshotKarakhanyan By now OP has confirmed that `T` is a generic type parameter.

Comment: @PitaJ does your class have a public default constructor? Also the class itself must be accessible (public).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Prototype Pattern

```
public E makeNew(E template) throws IllegalAccessException,InstantiationException{
    E newobject=(E)template.getClass().newInstance();
    return newobject;
}
```

Comment: of course same caveats as Andre's Answer.  You need a no-arg constructor.

Comment: and of course it is in a generic class define like  public class Name<E>  or public class Name<E extends Node>

Answer (score 0):

You can only create instances of known types. `T` is not something that comes with Java, but it is often used as an internal type parameter in a class that takes a type parameter (java generics).

As an example, say that you are creating a type parameterized linked list, that is, a linked list that you can use with any one data type as contents. If you would want an instance of this class that could only contain `String`s, you would instantiate it like so:

```
MyLinkedList<String> list = new MyLinkedList<String>();
```

The definition of such a class needs a type parameter, that will represent whatever class it was instantiated with, and would look something like this:

```
class MyLinkedList<T> {
    // implementation code
}
```

Inside that class, you can create instances of type T, and you would do it with `T t = new T();`, just like you'd expect. T will however refer to some other class at runtime, since T is just a type parameter.

That `T` type will however not be accessible outside the class.

If you're not implementing a type parameterized class, you would have to create a class of type T in order to instantiate it, and make sure to include it into whatever scope you want to use it in. I wouldn't recommend doing that though, because it Isn't very descriptive.